# Customize the scrollbar of my webpage

Tags: html, css

I am building a website that requires heavy customization and i also want to customize the want the scrollbar looks (ie: color, width, style, etc).
I currently have no idea on what to do.

Honestly, I'm working on a group project chrome experiment and i have not tried anything yet.
Any solution even for chrome only will help.

Comment: Keep in mind there's no standard way to do this, and various browsers allow various customizations of scrollbar colors.  Chrome is probably the most flexible from what I've seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE has supported this through IE propriatary non-standard CSS attributes such as:

```
scrollbar-base-color
scrollbar-face-color
scrollbar-track-color
scrollbar-3dlight-color
scrollbar-highlight-color
scrollbar-arrow-color
scrollbar-darkshadow-color
scrollbar-shadow-color
```

WebKit (Chrome and Safari) also [support this](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) using:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar-button
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner
::-webkit-resizer
```

What's pretty cool about WebKit is scrollbars can have an opacity, which makes for some pretty nice looking UI.

To my knowledge, there's no standard Mozilla way to support this (though there is an [open bug on this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790) so we can hope!)  There are, however, some [jQuery plugins](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) that create scrollable regions.  You still wouldn't get custom scrollbar colors on the document window itself.

**IE Example:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
     BODY {scrollbar-base-color: #ff00ff;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="height: 5000px;">
   IE Test
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebKit Example (Chrome/Safari):**

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 12px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,255,0.8); 
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,255,0.7); 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="height: 5000px;">
   WebKit Test
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WORKED LIKE MAGIC @Mike . Thanks so much. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer, you can use `scrollbar-base-color` in CSS to change the colours of scrollbars.

Other browsers may or may not support it, but it's non-standard.

For all other browsers, and to affect things such as actual appearance (width, arrow style, etc) you will need to program your own scrollbar in JavaScript, and it's a usability nightmare - don't do it!